# Segmentation fault c strcmp at last comparaison

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I'm currently trying to compare each String from a `char**` with another String.
In order to do so I tried to use `strcmp` but I get a Segmentation Fault. Then i tried to use a hand-made strcmp, and by testing I have been able to spot that my seg. fault happens when at the end of the comparaison between the word that I'm spotting and char[i].

Here are some lines and some tests so you can get the issue.

That's my main :

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char search[1024];

    ssize_t sz = getxattr(argv[1], "user.tag", search, sizeof(search) - 1);

    printf("Old tags: %s\n", search);

    if (sz != -1) {
        char **tab = malloc(sizeof(char **));

        tab = StringToTab(search);
        char *mot = malloc(sizeof(char));

        strcat(mot, argv[2]);
        strcat(mot, "\0");
        printf("\n%s\n", tab[3]);
        if (estDansLeTableau(tab, mot, nb_occ(search, ',') + 1)) {
            char *newtag = TabToString(removeFromTab(tab, argv[2],
                    (nb_occ(search, ','))
                ),
                (nb_occ(search, ','))
                );

            printf("\nICI 1\n");
            if (setxattr(argv[1], "user.tag", newtag, strlen(newtag), 0) == -1) {
                perror("ERREUR");
            }
            else {
                printf("\n La nouvelle liste de tag pour votre fichier est :  %s \n", newtag);
            }
            memset(newtag, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            printf("\nle tag demandé n'est pas dans la liste des tags de ce fichier\n");
        }
        memset(tab, 0, 0);
    }
    else {
        printf("\nLe fichier n'a aucun tag a enlever\n");
    }
}
```

Tab is coming from the fonction `StringToTab` who basically takes a string like `[abc,bcd,def]` and turn it into a `char**` like  `["abc","bcd","def"]`:

```
char **
StringToTab(char *s)
{
    char **tab = malloc((nb_occ(s, ',') + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    char *add = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char c = s[1];
    int j = 1;
    int i = 0;

    while (c != ']') {
        if (c == ',') {
            char *caracterVide = malloc(sizeof(&c));

            caracterVide = "\0";
            strcat(add, caracterVide);
            memset(caracterVide, 0, 0);
            printf("\nMot = %s\n", add);
            tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
            memcpy(tab[i], add, strlen(add));
            printf("\nAffected word = %s\n", tab[i]);
            memset(add, 0, sizeof(add));
            i++;
            j++;
            c = s[j];
        }
        else {
            char *sac = malloc(sizeof(&c));

            *sac = c;
            strcat(add, sac);
            memset(sac, 0, 0);
            printf("\nprefix = %s", add);
            j++;
            c = s[j];
        }
    }
    printf("\nMot = %s\n", add);
    tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    memcpy(tab[i], add, strlen(add));
    printf("\nAffected word = %s\n", tab[i]);
    memset(add, 0, 0);
    i++;
    j++;
    c = s[j];
    return tab;
}
```

Then we go to `estDansLeTableau` (=isInTheTab) which is gonna take the tab that we just had, the `argv[2]` which is the tag that I need to spot.

```
int
estDansLeTableau(char **t, char *m, int t_len)
{
    // 1 si le mot est dans le tableau, 0 sinon
    int j = 0;

    while (j < t_len) {
        printf("\nword 1 = %s, word 2 = %s\n", t[j], m);
        if (strcmp(t[j], m) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is a test where i'm trying to spot "lol" on the tab :

Old tags: [Amine,Chris,Sara,Kamelia,lol,Sarah,Sarah]

```
prefix = A
prefix = Am
prefix = Ami
prefix = Amin
prefix = Amine
Mot = Amine

Affected word = Amine

prefix = C
prefix = Ch
prefix = Chr
prefix = Chri
prefix = Chris
Mot = Chris

Affected word = Chris

prefix = S
prefix = Sa
prefix = Sar
prefix = Sara
Mot = Sara

Affected word = Sara

prefix = K
prefix = Ka
prefix = Kam
prefix = Kame
prefix = Kamel
prefix = Kameli
prefix = Kamelia
Mot = Kamelia

Affected word = Kamelia

prefix = l
prefix = lo
prefix = lol
Mot = lol

Affected word = lol

prefix = S
prefix = Sa
prefix = Sar
prefix = Sara
prefix = Sarah
Mot = Sarah

Affected word = Sarah

prefix = S
prefix = Sa
prefix = Sar
prefix = Sara
prefix = Sarah
Mot = Sarah

Affected word = Sarah

Kamelia

word 1 = Amine, word 2 = lol

word 1 = Chris, word 2 = lol

word 1 = Sara, word 2 = lol

word 1 = Kamelia, word 2 = lol

word 1 = lol, word 2 = lol
Segmentation fault
```

It's been 2 days that I'm stuck on it and i have NO CLUE on how to solve it S.O.S lmao! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Provide a minimal program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you just take this part :
`int estDansLeTableau(char** t, char *m, int t_len){
    
    int j = 0;
    while(j<t_len){
        printf("\nword 1 = %s, word 2 = %s\n", t[j], m); 
        if(strcmp(t[j], m) == 0){
            return 1;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}`

With the t=["abc","lol","cde"] and m="lol", it won't work

Comment: DId you yourself try to call this function for these arrays?

Comment: And yes I've just tried with these array @Vlad and it works, it's coming from the way I initialise my array I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the memory allocations are for the size of a pointer. On my system that is eight bytes. That could work as long as there are no elements more than seven characters.

```
char *caracterVide = malloc(sizeof(&c));
char *add = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

There are also memory leaks.

```
char **tab = malloc(sizeof(char **));
tab = StringToTab(search);
```

The assignment following the `malloc` overwrites the value returned by malloc and that memory can not be freed.

This is very curious.

```
char *sac = malloc(sizeof(&c));
*sac = c;
strcat(add, sac);
```

There is nothing to ensure that `sac` is zero terminated. The concatenation could, by pure chance, add one character or it could iterate until a zero is found and possibly crash the program.

Here is one approach to taking the original string and breaking it into items separated by commas.
`strspn` and `strcspn` are very useful for counting characters. `strspn` stops counting at the first non-matching character or the terminating zero and `strcspn` stops at the first matching character or the terminating zero.
This does not show the items character by character but that could be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** StringToTab(char *s) {
    char **tab = NULL;
    char *comma = s;
    char *item = s;
    int count = 0;
    int span = 0;

    while ( *item) {// loop to terminating zero
        item += strcspn ( item, ",");//count of characters that are not ,
        if ( *item) {
            ++item;//advance past ,
        }
        ++count;//add one for each comma
    }
    ++count;//add one for item fillowing last comma
    //allocate extra sentinel pointer
    if ( NULL == ( tab = calloc ( sizeof *tab, ( count + 1)))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "calloc problem\n");
        return tab;
    }
    count = 0;

    item = s;
    item += strspn ( s, "[");//count of characters that are [

    while ( *item) {//not at terminating zero
        comma = item;//set comma to the same as item
        comma += strcspn ( item, ",");//count of characters that are not ,
        if ( *comma) {
            span = comma - item;
        }
        else {//at the terminating zero
            span = strcspn ( item, "]");//count of characters that are not ]
        }
        //allocate memory for each item
        if ( NULL == ( tab[count] = malloc ( span + 1))) {//span characters plus terminating zero
            fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
            return tab;
        }
        strncpy ( tab[count], item, span);//copy span characters
        tab[count][span] = 0;//set terminating zero
        ++count;
        item = comma;
        if ( *comma) {//not terminating zero
            ++item;//increment past ,
        }
    }
    return tab;
}

int estDansLeTableau(char **t, char *m) {
    // 1 si le mot est dans le tableau, 0 sinon
    int j = 0;

    while ( t[j]) {
        printf("\nword 1 = %s, word 2 = %s\n", t[j], m);
        if (strcmp(t[j], m) == 0) {
            return j;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **tab = NULL;
    char test[] = "[Amine,Chris,Sara,Kamelia,lol,Sarah,Sarah]";
    char mot[] = "lol";
    int each = 0;
    int match = 0;

    printf("Old tags: %s\n", test);

    tab = StringToTab ( test);
    if ( tab) {
        if ( 0 <= ( match = estDansLeTableau(tab, mot))) {
            printf("match %s at %d\n", mot, match);
        }

        each = 0;
        while ( tab[each]) {
            free ( tab[each]);
            ++each;
        }
        free ( tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this answer! 

Through, the segmenation fault is still there, I tried to re-implement everything following your indications (and using your ```StringtoTab```)  and ```estDansLeTableau``` is still throwing me a Seg. fault while doing the strcmp.